# Are post-docs required for faculty jobs in statistics?

Tags: phd, career-path, postdocs, tenure-track, assistant-professor

Is it possible to become a tenure-track assistant professor of statistics department directly after the PhD, without having to do a postdoc? I'm interested in the top schools in the US (i.e., the Ivy League).

In Canada, a good PhD graduate from a statistics program would go into academia without having to do the postdoc, but I am not sure what the situation is like in the US.

Comment: I hope your'e aware that you are shooting at an awfully small target. There are only 8 ivy league schools and most of them are pretty small. They also pretty much get their pick of top candidates every year and if their programs are small they won't hire every year.

Comment: A related question (whether it's possible to become a professor without a PhD) already exists: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/professorship-without-phd-in-the-united-states. Accordingly I don't see why this is off-topic. Duplicate maybe, but not off-topic.

Comment: @Allure I agree that it's on-topic. However, given that the only possible answer is "You can get any job if you can demonstrate that you're good enough" and that the question kind of contradicts itself (the asker wants to know about "the situation in the US" but asks only about the Ivy League), I'm not sure it's worth reopening.

Comment: I know of a statistics department (not Ivy League) that just hired two tenure track faculty members: one is finishing a post doc, and one has just finished a PhD. Also note that of the top 10 US statistics departments maybe half are Ivy League.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a faculty job without a postdoc - in fact it's possible to get a faculty job without a PhD (see [Noah Snyder's answer to a related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/professorship-without-phd-in-the-united-states/8430#8430)).

Of course, what is *possible* and what is *likely* can be completely different. It's possible to be dealt a royal flush in poker but not at all likely. There are hundreds of thousands of professors worldwide and chances are the number who haven't done a postdoc can be counted on two hands. Since you're further restricting the sample to the top schools, well, let's just say that it's about as likely as being dealt a royal flush.