# Why are the German professors addressed as Prof. Dr. XXX?

Tags: professorship, etiquette, germany

I notice that in Germany, basically all the professors are addressed as Prof. Dr. XXX, say Prof. Dr. Mueller.

However, in other parts of the world, only Prof. would be sufficient,  <del>since a non-doctor can never be a University professor.</del>

So why are the German professors addressed this way? Isn't it kind of redundant?

Comment: Logic and customs don't mix.

Comment: Who said a non-doctor can never be a University professor?

Comment: I've often wondered how many titles one could accumulate.  If a university professor were to join the military and then go into politics, could she become Frau Chancellor Colonel Professor Doctor Schmidt?

Comment: Professor is (usually) not a title, but is associated with the profession. If you quit to become chancellor, I think you cannot call yourself professor anymore.

Comment: Just to clarify, your assertion that "a non-doctor can never be a university professor" is not entirely true.  Adjunct faculty, professors of practice, and other such titles are used for teaching faculty without a PhD, and are often referred to as  "Prof. XXX"  Though generally, these are not tenure-eligible positions.

Comment: It's worth noting that we often do this with titles in English as well. For instance, "Her Royal Highness Queen Elizabeth II". The "Queen" title implies the HRH title in much the same way Professor implies Doctor. Using a full title is generally to indicate increased respect.

Comment: I've seen that titles are taken very seriously is Germany, with e.g. triple doctorates titled by *Dr. Dr. Dr.* or *DDDr*.

Comment: Sergeant Frank Drebin, Detective Lieutenant Police Squad

Comment: I don't know for sure if the logic is the same, but in German when referring to a medical doctor one says "Frau/Herr Doktor K." - the polite honorific of Frau or Herr (Mr. or Mrs.) remains, even when using the job title. As to *why* this is so - as @F'x says, logic and customs don't mix.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8330/64

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens In Germany, it's a title. The "Dr" is even part of your name. However, the assumption of the question is flawed: except in very formal circumstances (like a laudation), this form of addressing rarely happens. At least in MINT; I'm told that people ... care more about their titles elsewhere.

Comment: @emory "Professor" means something else than "a person who teaches in a lecture hall" in Germany. Afaik, there is no way to become a university professor in Germany without a doctorate (see Eekhoorn's answer, though). People in professor-like positions may be (like to be) referred to as "Professor" but they won't have the same rights and, afaik, in particular not the legal title in the same way university professors have.

Comment: @Raphael what are the rights of German professors? In the US, everyone is equal.  The homeless have the same rights as university professors who have the same rights as the President.  My degree has verbiage about "rights, privileges, and honors" but as far as I can tell there are none.

Comment: @emory The fifth article of our Grundgesetz assures researchers [*academic freedom*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademische_Freiheit). In practice, you *can* be hired for specific projects and/or courses in which case that freedom is limited. Since there is little else in senior researcher positions these days, afaik, only (full) professors are truly free in what they do. (I may be wrong here; I remembered a phrasing different from Art. 5 GG addressing professors specifically but apparently that's somewhere else.)

Comment: @DavidHall: No, I don't think the logic is "the same", what you point out is rather a separate issue, namely that addressing in German normally works by using <personal title> <degree(s)> <name>, rather than just <degree(s)> <name>, as in English. Therefore, when directly *addressing* someone with a rank/degree, it is (w.l.o.g. concerning Herr/Frau) *Herr Doktor X*, *Herr Kapitän Y*, *Herr Professor Doktor Z*.

Comment: Wait till you see Austrian academia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Germany, professorships and doctorates are considered to be "legal" titles, and have special status not accorded to other degrees and professions. In particular, university professors in Germany are *Beamte* (appointed civil servants, sg: "Beamter"/"Beamtin"), which places them in a relatively small class of government employees.

It is to be noted that a professor in a German university can be called "Herr Professor" or "Frau Professorin" only so long as he or she is actively working as a professor. Following retirement or leaving the university profession, it is technically not permitted to use the title.

Thus, in this sense, the appellation "Professor"/"Professorin" is legally part of someone's name, and should therefore be used in formal greetings and salutations. (This can sometimes be annoying—for example, in a physician's waiting room, you can hear them call for "Frau Professorin Schmidt!")

Comment: I know several professors who just introduce themselves with "Herr/Frau X" in order to avoid awkwardness. Regarding retirement, though, I have seen "Prof. em." (for emeritus) several times. I *think* professors (at least those with older contracts) kind of keep the title in retirement.

Comment: Professor is not legally part of the name, the doctorate is, however. And even after retirement the Professor can be used. Germans like titles, Austrians like them even more.

Comment: _It is to be noted that a professor in a German university can be called "Herr Professor" or "Frau Professor" only so long as he or she is actively working as a professor; following retirement or leaving the university profession, it is technically not permitted to use the title._ This is wrong: cf. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademischer_Grad#Abgrenzung_zu_Titeln), [Hochschullehrerbund](http://hlb.de/fileadmin/hlb-global/downloads/members_only/Infoblaetter_Mitglieder/hlb-Infoblatt_Titelfuehrungsbefugnis_bei_Ausscheiden.pdf)

Comment: There are some flaws in this answer:
a) "Professor" is *not* part of someone's name (otherwise you would have the option to add it to your passport (you can do this with "Dr." which is part of the name)
b) You do not loose the permission to use the title after leaving university. The rules vary, but https://hlb.de/fileadmin/hlb-global/downloads/members_only/Infoblaetter_Mitglieder/hlb-Infoblatt_Titelfuehrungsbefugnis_bei_Ausscheiden.pdf gives a good overview.

Comment: Okay, but why Professor **Dr.**?

Comment: This answer makes several factually wrong statements.

Comment: @user2705196 Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 20):

In Germany, in rare cases also non-doctors can become a professor. Then it's just "Prof. Müller". Regarding Doctors, we don't have a "PhD" title. "Dr." is the official title for a doctor which is traditionally a prefix to the full name.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)#Germany

Comment: Very good answer. Those few professors without a doctorate are usually very successful people from the industry, government, media etc.

Comment: It can also be the case that the person *is* a doctor, but not from a university or country whose titles are automatically recognized in Germany (and didn't go through all to trouble to do so).

Comment: I don’t think this really answers the question: both points you give here apply just as much in other countries that don’t stack their honorifics.

Comment: @PLL, but that's the way it is in Germany, I don't know how this is handled in other countries.

Comment: It should be noted that these people are almost certainly not university professors (a job which, iirc, by definition requires not only a doctorate but also habilitation or something similar). There are other forms of higher ed in Germany, and a docent there may be called "Professor" somewhat informally, but they would not be able to, say, have doctorands on their own. (If this is incorrect and there are indeed university professors with the right to confer doctorates, I'd appreciate a reference.)

Comment: Doctorates are conferred by the faculty, professors at universities can advise, professors at colleges (_Fachhoschschulen_) can be examiners but not official advisors.

Comment: @Raphael An example of a university professor without without doctorate is Prof. Henke (now at DLR).