# How should I refer to PIs in a statement of purpose (US)?

Tags: etiquette, united-states, statement-of-purpose, titles

I am applying for PhD programs at graduate schools in the US and I am wondering how I should refer to researchers that I name in my statement of purpose? In particular, I am wondering whether to refer to people that have titles of 'Assistant Professor' or 'Associate Professor' as Prof. or Dr.? I have heard that the prefix 'Prof.' tends to be reserved for full, tenured Professors - is that true?

(note, that I have edited the question due to its similarity to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37037/101), to focus specifically on the context of a statement of purpose for US grad schools)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37037/101

Comment: @MarkMeckes it is quite similar. Thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps what I will do is edit the question to be specific about prefixes used in personal statement for US grad schools.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr. In a formal situation, be formal, otherwise...

The US is pretty informal about titles (unless the professor is from a German university). So either should do *in general* (see below). Even an assistant professor can be referred to as "professor". It is even possible, if rare, that an Associate Professor won't actually hold a doctorate. But no one is likely to be offended.

You might, however, after a first usage, be told that some other thing is more appropriate. Then you should just do that.

My own doctoral advisor *did* have a Germainc type doctorate and additional *beyond doctorate* degrees. But he was happy enough in the US to be referred to with any reasonable designation. I also had a colleague who was at least an Associate Professor but held no doctorate. He did, however, participate in very important theoretical research - with Edsger Dijkstra, actually.

**But** this is how you refer to a person *in person* or in email and such. For a more formal designation, such as in a paper, you may need to refer to an actual title. "Associate Professor Smythe" or such. The context you give, suggests a formal title is called for - an application.

Comment: Hello Buffy, FYI: I edited my question to focus more specifically on a statement of purpose, due to its similarity to a previous question.

Comment: See my last paragraph. You are in a more formal situation, so a more formal designation is probably better. Getting it "wrong" won't have a devastating effect, however.

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard that the prefix 'Prof.' tends to be reserved for full, tenured Professors - is that true?

For formal writing in the US, that is false.  Assistant, Associate, and Full Professors are all titled "Prof."  This would be especially true if a student is writing.

Exceptions include:  University websites, press releases, and promotion documents.  In these cases, the exact rank is specified.

In other countries and in informal language, practices can be totally different.