# Should you state multiple degree titles in your CV next to your name?

Tags: cv, degree, titles

If I hold a MSc and a BSc should and I want to show that next to my name in my CV, should I use:

> Sosi, MSc, BSc

or simply the highest one:

> Sosi, MSc

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55275/do-academic-titles-matter-in-cv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is an academic CV (as this site is about Academia), then you should *not* include your titles next to your name in your CV, but describe them in the "Education" section.

Answer (score 4):

Highest followed by any professional titles, i.e., XXX PhD, PE